# JavaScript - Gulp/Browserify: SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

For whatever reason, my `browserify` and `gulp` stopped working. For example, here's my `gulp js` script to bundle my javascript.

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src('src/js/*.js')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
    return browserify('./src/js/main', { debug: true })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
/*    .pipe(streamify(uglify()))*/
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'JavaScript has been bundled with Browserify!'}));
    // .pipe(livereload());
});
```

and here is `main.js`:

```
var ajaxChng = require('./ajax-changelog');
ajaxChng();
```

and inside `src/js/ajax-changelog.js` is this:

```
module.exports = {
    console.log('Hello World');
};
```

But when I do `gulp js`, I get:

```
λ gulp js
[19:11:50] Using gulpfile c:\wamp\www\osrsmap\gulpfile.js
[19:11:50] Starting 'js'...

events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the rest of the error? The stack trace is the most important part.

Comment: Noone noticed that the 'helpful' error context is completely wrong? That is the entire message, there's no stack to be had and the code snippet it always shows is `events.js:<some line>\n      throw err; // unhandled 'error' event\n       ^\n        SyntaxError: Unexpected token` no matter what the actual source code is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wait... this is not valid javascript:

```
module.exports = {
    console.log('Hello World');
};
```

Maybe you meant this?

```
module.exports = function () {
    console.log('Hello World');
};
```

Comment: I hate when this happens!